# Invalid argument (callbackUrlScheme): must be a valid URL scheme: "com.test.app"

Tags: flutter, oauth2client, outlook-calendar

**I am unable to run this code**

when I am try to run this code using [oauth2_client](https://pub.dev/packages/oauth2_client) This package shows an error

[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: Invalid argument (callbackUrlScheme): must be a valid URL scheme: "com.test.app"

```
static Future fetchOutlookCalender() async {
var client = OAuth2Client(
authorizeUrl:
'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize',
tokenUrl: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token',
redirectUri: 'msauth://com.test.app/gYfucgrOlZ3FLWgYctqk1bCxZbo%3D',
customUriScheme: 'com.test.app');

var token = await client.getTokenWithAuthCodeFlow(
clientId: 'f865f294-3647-43d7-bc6e-f726f06nnno56be',
scopes: ['openid profile offline_access user.read calendars.read']);
log('accesstoken:' '${token.accessToken}');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the docs, when registering your application on the OAuth provider, try not to use HTTPS as the scheme part of the redirect URI which you probably did, because in that case, your application won't intercept the server redirection, as it will automatically handle by the system browser.
Just use a custom scheme, such as "my.test.app" or any other scheme you want.